# AWS S3 Bucket hosting: Specific routes

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm hosting my Angular page in an s3 bucket, deployed by CloudFront.

Everything is workin as long as I don't open a specific route.

- www.mydomain.com works
- www.mydomain.com/export doesn't work. I get an error: The specified
  key does not exist from S3

The routing is working on my machine (localhost/export is no problem). How can I tell S3 that /export is not a file but should be handled by my angular router?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The www.mydomain.com/export route does not exist on CloudFront as it is just a front-end route. I think the error that is being returned will be a 404 error because CloudFront will be telling you that there is no static asset at www.mydomain.com/export.

You simply need to configure CloudFront to respond to all 404 errors by serving the index.html page.

You can do this by configuring a custom error response (see the details via the following link):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html

Settings should be:

- Http Error Code: 404
- Customize Error Response: Yes
- Response Page Path: /index.html
- Http Response Code: 200